# Unable to properly hear myself singing, but can hear well playing or singing others

Tags: voice, self-learning, ear-training, hearing

I'm looking on a voice (singing) a little like an instrument where you don't use muscles on fingers, but muscles inside your neck/throat.

I got some practice in playing bass (guitar/double-bass) and also I'm dancing/singin in folklore group (supported by cimbali band). From perspective of others, I/we 've found that **I'm not able to sing clearly the melody (reproduce it, nor the pitch, by voice).** However, in my head I can hear my voice as clear production of the "original" melody, which suits the singing/playing of others.

Getting bigger perspective, while playing the instrument, **I can produce by ear the tones that fits the played song** and this is also confirmed by others. Also, when hearing somebody else, I can hear if his voice/his playing is or isn't in tune.

Last, but not least, I haven't been playing any instrument in my early age and I haven't got any musical "leading" till my 20 years.

**I cannot find what exactly is my issue with the hearing and I'd like to find out a way how to improve it.**

---

Q is similar to this ( [Unable to sing, but not tone deaf](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/17666/unable-to-sing-but-not-tone-deaf) ), but I don't feel this is the same (even that I agree that the **basic ear traning** can help with the topic).

Comment: You say others indicate you cannot sing the melody clearly, but you hear your voice clearly in your head as a more accurate reproduction--are the others unable to hear you well because you sing too quietly, or do they think you sing the wrong notes?

Comment: It is about wrong notes, there is no issue in regards to volume level.

Comment: Trying to confirm here: do you hear your own notes as wrong, or do you think you sing accurately?

Comment: I got feeling that I sing accurately. Tried also as 'bocca chiusa' (humming) with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't tell if you are singing right or wrong by your own, seems like your only option is to find a teacher (if not a formal one, some friend to guide you).

This way you will be able to learn by "brute force". What I mean is: you can be told to sing higher or lower to reach a certain note, and memorize it once you do, even if you don't understand it completely. With time you will make sense out of it and incorporate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can record your voice while listening to some song and then listen where did you went wrong (if at all). Also singing to a tuner helped me get the tone shifts more accurately. Maybe you hear the pitch after the tone is settled but the shift is not as good.